# attempt to index a nil value (field '?') on FiveM essentialmode

Tags: lua

i have problem in one part of the code, i´m not coder, i looked over on the internet but i didnt find anything that would help, the problem is on line 234 which is `if groups[Users[source].getGroup()]:canTarget(group) then` idk what to do, this is the error

`Error running call reference function for resource essentialmode: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:351: server/main.lua:234: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
stack traceback:
        server/main.lua:234: in upvalue 'ref'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:337: in function citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:336
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:336: in function citizen:/scripcfx ting/lua/scheduler.lua:335>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:351: in function citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:322`

```
function addGroupCommand(command, group, callback, callbackfailed, suggestion)
commands[command] = {}
commands[command].perm = math.maxinteger
commands[command].group = group
commands[command].cmd = callback
commands[command].callbackfailed = callbackfailed

if suggestion then
    if not suggestion.params or not type(suggestion.params) == "table" then suggestion.params = {} end
    if not suggestion.help or not type(suggestion.help) == "string" then suggestion.help = "" end

    commandSuggestions[command] = suggestion
end

ExecuteCommand('add_ace group.' .. group .. ' command.' .. command .. ' allow')

RegisterCommand(command, function(source, args)
    if groups[Users[source].getGroup()]:canTarget(group) then
        callback(source, args, Users[source])
    else
        callbackfailed(source, args, Users[source])
    end
end)

debugMsg("Group command added: " .. command .. ", requires group: " .. group)          end
```

Comment: Why array `Users` starts with capital letter, but array `groups` doesn't?  Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe `Users[GetPlayerName(source)]` would be more correct?

Answer (score 0):

Lua only accepts indices starting from 1, and I usually got this error when the index was 0. So you can check if `source` or `Users[source].getGroup()` might be equal to 0 make sure they are always `>= 1`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for the future reference of others that land here:

When getting errors in the logs like

`citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:351: server/main.lua:234: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')`

it tends to be because of the data fetched from the Database is empty.

For example,

```
Error running call reference function for resource esx_identity: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:405: @esx_identity/server/main.lua:11: attempt to index a nil value (field '?')
stack traceback:
@esx_identity/server/main.lua:11: in upvalue 'ref'
```

Line 11 in `esx_identity/server/main.lua` is:

`if result[1].firstname ~= nil then`

The `firstname` referenced is an empty value coming back from the database. The SQL query is usually very close to the problem line of code.

Check your database for rows that contain empty values and remove or fix any that exist.